# Echo html files with variables

Tags: php, html

I need to be able to include an html file that has variables in it, and then have those variables replaced with their values, and then finally echoed out.
This is my PHP:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$CONTENT="CONTENT";
define(PAGE_TITLE, "title");
include("index.html");
```

and my HTML file:

```
<html>
<title>{PAGE_TITLE}</title>
<p>{$CONTENT}</p>
<p>{$ARR}</p>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to echo the PHP parts still. It's the same as if you put PHP outside the PHP tags. `?> echo 'hi';` Your output is `echo 'hi';`

Comment: Sounds like you could use a templating engine.  I imagine there are quite a few to choose from in PHP.

Comment: @chris85 I've seen plenty of other softwares do this the way I am trying to,

Comment: You've run this code?

Comment: The mixing of variables and constants makes it more involved than it has to be. Can you settle on one or the other, or hold keys and values in an array? With that I would lean towards a `preg_replace()` or a `preg_replace_callback()` on the content of `index.html`, and then echo it out

Comment: @mike.k If I did that, and any other content that was the same as the variable was in there, wouldn't it replace that too?

Comment: That should be the objective, that is why `{$CONTENT}` would be a unique string and not expected to exist outside of this context. Stand by, I'll provide an example in an answer.

Comment: @mike.k Well, it boils down to this, I can use short tags: `<?=` or I could use your method. What do you think would work better.

Comment: Short tags are better.

Comment: Don't complicate life. Use a template engine such as [tag:dwoo]. Its syntax is like what you described and accepts more needs such as looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php shorttags:

```
<html>
<title><?=PAGE_TITLE?></title>
<p><?=$CONTENT?></p>
<p><?=$ARR?></p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include php tags in your html elements, and if you want to output the value of the variable you need to echo it.

Try this:

```
<html>
<title><?php echo PAGE_TITLE; ?></title>
<p><?php echo $CONTENT; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $ARR; ?></p>
</html>
```